# jQuery $(document).ready() failing in IE6 but only after clearing Temporary Internet Files

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-6

I'm experiencing problems with $(document).ready *not getting executed* in IE6, but only after clearing the Temporary Internet Files (so in fact the very first time this page is loaded). On refreshing the page or on later page loads, everything works fine.

This is the current setup:

- Portal page with frames, this portal page also has a window.load method (maybe we have a race problem with jQuery ready ??):

  ```
  window.onload = function () {
  try {
      expireCookie("COOKIE%2DID");
      loadMenu();
  } catch (pcbException) {
      reportError(pcbException);
  }
  }
  ```

  - In this portal page, our current page gets loaded. At the bottom of this page we have:

> <script language="javascript">
>
> try{
>
> $("#CR").remove();
>
> }
>    catch(ex){
>       }
>
> $(document).ready(function() {
>     alert(typeof $); // check if method is getting executed
>     RendererPageIsLoading(); // loads data in comboboxes and hides divs
>      });
>
> </script>
>   </body>

I'm using the latest version of jQuery (1.4.2).
**Edit**: jquery is getting loaded in the head section of the current page:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://fulldomain/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Following topic didn't bring any solutions:
[jQuery $(document).ready() failing in IE6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463800/jquery-document-ready-failing-in-ie6)

Comment: How are you loading jQuery? This is probably the reason for your error.

Comment: How is the ‘current page’ getting ‘loaded’? Are you talking about setting `iframe src` to it in the parent page?

Comment: We're using frameset/frames, not an iframe. Code used (target=frame):

if (typeof target.location == "object") {
target.location.href = url;
} else {
target.src = url;
  }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone suggested (he did remove his answer later on) that attaching a method to the window.onload did detach the method defined in the $(document).ready() event. However since the error only happened the first time the page was loaded, in my opinion this had to be a cache problem.

After further investigation we found out that IE6 was having problems with a transparent png that didn't get loaded correctly. Therefor the browser is waiting for the image to load and IE6 waits on images before it triggers the DOM ready event.

Conclusion: also check for **transparent png** images if having problems with IE6.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a script immediately before the "/body" tag, you don't need to use:

```
$(document).ready(...);
```

As the document IS ready (bar from "/body" and "/html").

It is really useful if you have an external JavaScript file that may be loaded faster than the page - in which case it delays the execution until the DOM is ready (or in some browsers the DOM and HTTP requests... which is more like window.onload, which waits for all the images, for example).

Comment: It's probably still a good idea to have `$(document).ready(...);`, in the event the code is moved around in the document later on. This way, the code doesn't have to be modified.

Comment: I agree with Christopher. `$(document).ready(...);` also allows to move all your javascript to a seperate file and seperate it completely from your HTML. I think this is very usefull for larger code files.

Comment: I actually think you should use $(document).ready(...) when it is appropriate - not as a rule or "just in case". Being a developer means thinking about your code and not writing code that isn't required. @Christopher Parker - add it when you move the code, that is when it is needed - not before. @Bart - add it when you move your script into a separate file - not before.