# why does this script not work in IE6?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working on and off on a horizontal accordion. It's not working perfectly at the moment but i've just got to change a few bits. The code is very rough and I intend to make it a bit more graceful once it works.

It functions perfectly in every browser apart from ie6..initially when it loads in the page all you can see is the 6th panel (labelled df6)...then if you click on that the accordion seems to spring in to life....all the panels appear and it seems to work just fine. I can't think of any reason for this..

Any ideas? I'm at a complete loss with this :(

http://boudaki.com/testing/carousel/test.html

Comment: It doesn't work so well in Firefox Either. You may use existing libraries to do that, as Mootools, JQuery, ...

Comment: Huh? What do you mean exactly? It works fine in my version of firefox (3.6.6). Which version are you using and what exactly is not working?

Comment: jquery under ie6 is completely screwy at best. a lot of basic dom functions don't work. Since IE6 is only partially supported by MS (see http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifesupsps/#Internet_Explorer) may be you should not worry about it :)

Comment: Thanks for fixing the typo's Peter. I'll try and be more vigilant in future ;)

Comment: A surprising number of companies still require IE6 support, so he may not have much choice in worrying about IE6.
My experience with it is that it also matters a lot which version of IE6 you're using. Seemingly tiny differences can have a dramatic impact. IE6 is a hell, and we're still not out of it.

Comment: The company I work for still support it and many of our clients expect their sites to display correctly in it. I've also found that a lot of our clients are still running IE6 as their default browser in their offices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! Thankyou Elf King! Your comment about jquery and IE6 led me to a google search which turned up another stack overflow post:

[jQuery $(document).ready() failing in IE6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463800/jquery-document-ready-failing-in-ie6)

It seems moving my script to the bottom of the page and removing the document.ready fixed it!!

Many thanks and apologies I should have googled this more thoroughly :)

Answer (score 1):

For me this did not work well in IE7 either! However, I was able to make it work properly by setting the id's of the list items in the markup. Element ID's shouldn't be the kind of things change often, so perhaps this can be done, rather that set it in the onload function... Is there some reason you were doing it that way?

```
<body>          
 <ul id="accordion">     
  <li id="handle1">
    <a href="#">df1</a>
    <div>content1
    </div>
  </li>     
  <li id="handle2">
    <a href="#">df2</a>
    <div>content2
    </div>
  </li>       
  <li id="handle3">
    <a href="#">df3</a>
    <div>content3
    </div>
  </li>        
  <li id="handle4">
    <a href="#">df4</a>
    <div>content4
    </div>
  </li>         
  <li id="handle5">
    <a href="#">df5</a>
    <div>content5
    </div>
  </li>               
  <li id="handle6">
    <a href="#">df6</a>
    <div>content6
    </div>
  </li>        
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, I didn't get a chance to test ie7 but I imagine it's the same problem as ie6 was having. Thanks for letting me know! I'm dynamically assigning those id's so it's nice and easy to use in the future. I usually put things like this in plugins so it can be re-used by other developers in my workplace who aren't very adept at js.