# jQuery object expected error in asp.net page with master site

Tags: asp.net, jquery, datepicker

The error i get seems to be centered around jquery finding what it's in (window,document, etc.).  Right now i'm just trying to implement the jQuery datepicker.  the project has a master page, where i placed my script references.

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Styles/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.datePicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/date.js"></script>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

in my aspx file for the page i am trying to implement the date picker, the code looks like this.

i placed this in the header place holder

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(window).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=this.tbTestPass.ClientID %>").datePicker();
});  
</script>
```

This is the asp control i am trying to apply the datepicker to.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbTestPass" runat="server" Width="120px"></asp:TextBox>
```

I have tried document and window for jquery context, but they both throw the same error.  What noob mistake am i making?

Comment: The error occurs on the line containing "$(window).ready(function () {"

Comment: i just stumbled on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463800/jquery-document-ready-failing-in-ie6

one of the answers showed a way to debug using alert(typeof $)

this returned as undefined.  so this leads me to jquery hasn't loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found that linking to http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js fixed the object missing.  pointing to a local file was not working. not sure why, but this will do and suit my needs i think.

Answer (score 1):

Verify Jquery(.js) file folder path is resolved properly from the application as well as in the IIS.

i had the same situation, i had Jquery.js file under Scripts folder(Scripts/Jquery.js).
but when i went to iis, i am not able to see the Scripts folder.

later i came to know there there is an Script virtual directory in IIS when is taking precedence over the local Script folder.