# previous button jquery

Tags: jquery

I have these two elements in my page:

```
<input type='button' value="undo" style="display:none" onClick = "undoFunction()"/>
<input type='checkbox'  onClick = "ajaxFunction()"/>
```

I want when ever I click checkbox, undo button appears. I have used jquery but something is wrong. it doesn't work.

this is my whole function:

```
function ajaxFunction(){
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form input:checkbox").click(function () {
            var hrefAdd = ($(this).nextAll('a').attr("href"));
            var word = savequery();
            var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
            try{
                // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
                ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } catch (e){
                    // Internet Explorer Browsers
                    try{
                        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                        } catch (e) {
                            try{
                                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                                } catch (e){
                                    // Something went wrong
                                    alert("Your browser broke!");

                                    return false;
                                    }
                                }
                        }

                var queryString ="?Word=" + word + "&Link_Add=" + hrefAdd  ;
                    ajaxRequest.open("GET","ajax_request.php" + queryString , true);
                    $(this).prev('input[type="button"]').show();
                    $(this).css("display","none");


                ajaxRequest.send(null);
                });
        });
}
```

Comment: You really don't need to wrap your JS code into `function ajaxFunction() {}`, you also do not need and `onClick` attribute in checkbox element. `$("form input:checkbox").click()` does the whole binding to element for you.

Comment: Another hint: you can make your AJAX GET call to `ajax_request.php` lot more simple using [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like:

```
 $(this).prev('input[type="button"]').show()
```

The `=` instead of `:`

And a small "better practice" note:

Better approach would be to define your event handlers in non-obtrusive way (in case of jQuery in a domready callback:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        $(this).prev('input[type="button"]').show();
    });
});
```

Same with the click event button input.

UPDATE:

Your whole JS code (of course wrapped in `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tags) should look similar to this (as I've written in comment to your original question - you don't need to wrap a domready callback in another function)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form input:checkbox").click(function () {
        var hrefAdd = ($(this).nextAll('a').attr("href"));
        var word = savequery();
        var data = {"Word": word, "Link_Add": hrefAdd};

        $.get('ajax_request.php', data);
        $(this).prev('input[type="button"]').show();
        $(this).css("display","none");
    });
});
```

I've omitted e.g. a success callback from an ajax call since you don't have one in your original code, but you can find all in [Jquery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) docs.

UPDATE 2:

Ok, here's complete page which does what you want (except that it may spit out an 404 error after ajax call depending, whether `ajax_request.php` exists or not). Does this work for you?

```
<html>
  <head><title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" encoding="utf-8">
      $(function() {
          $("form input:checkbox").click(function () {
              var hrefAdd = ($(this).nextAll('a').attr("href"));
              var word = savequery();
              var data = {"Word": word, "Link_Add": hrefAdd};

              $.get('ajax_request.php', data);
              $(this).prev('input[type="button"]').show();
              $(this).css("display","none");
          });
      });
      // just a mock function to make a call to it in checkbox click callback work
      var savequery = function() {
        return "foo";
      }
    </script>
    <form action="" method="get">
      <input type="button" value="undo" style="display:none"/>
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <a href="http://example.com/#foo">test link to fill hrefAdd</a>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes. it is like what you are saying. I just put some part of the code here. "=" also doesn't work

Comment: I've also missed that you have invalid HTML markup (missing closing `"` in `onClick="undoFunction()"` of the button input. Isn't this the problem?

Comment: Ok, as Umair has written, you'll have to provide us more data: Isn't there any error in you JS console (either firebug console in FF or js console in Chrome)?

Comment: I add my code to the post. can you please have a look at it? I checked my code in that site and realized that when ever I put the function in a "function ajaxFunction(){" it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. I did what ever you said but know I get an " Object expected" error on line "$(document).ready(function(){"

Comment: I've posted you a whole page, try it without changes and report, if this works for you.

Comment: What browser do you use? Internet Explorer? Try to replace the first line in `<script>` with `jQuery(function() {` or try other solutions [metioned in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463800/jquery-document-ready-failing-in-ie6)

Comment: Yes, I am using IE. I checked your suggestion. again the same error. I will try solutions mentioned in that question. thanks

Comment: I tried all the suggestions. no change. typeof $ is undefined. ofcourse when I checked "akloboucnik" file separately it works. but I have multiple javascript functions in my js file along with a jQuery function.

Comment: Ok, if you don't mind, give me all you code, I'll try to debug it.

Comment: thanks for your help. now I don't get the error and typeof$ is function, but when I click the checkbox nothing happens. sorry that I can't send you my code.

Comment: Well, without seeing the actual code I'm afraid I can't really help you. What about e.g. renaming all the functions and variables (to names like funcionA or varB), so I won't (at least so easily) be able to guess the real purpose of the code - if this is the problem?

Comment: finally solved. thank you very much for your help and following up my problem.

Comment: Great! Won't you mind accepting my answer or voting it up, if it helped?

Comment: sure. but when I want to vote up your answer it says that I should have 15 reputations. is there any thing that I can help?

Comment: Thanks, never mind you can't vote up, accepting itself hopefuly marks answer as valid for other possible readers.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me.

```
<input type='button' value="undo" style="display:none" /> 
<input type='checkbox' class='cb_button' /> 

<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready( function() {
    $(".cb_button").click( function() {
      $(this).prev(":button").show();
    });
  });
</script>
```

The document.ready function is like a load for the page.  Inside of there, we are saying, find the all the checkboxes with class 'cb_button', and set it so their click event does this function.

In the function, it tells it to get the particular checkboxes's prior sibling which has type='button.

If you want to toggle, you can check to see if it's checked with the .attr('checked'):

```
if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
  $(this).prev(":button").show()
} else {
  $(this).prev(":button").hide()
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please show us your complete code, the answer posted by akloboucnik seems to be correct. You can check it running here

http://jsfiddle.net/tDDV2/

check your JS logs and see if you can figure out the issue

Comment: Thanks for this site. I add my code to the post. can you please have a look at it? I checked my code in that site and realized that when ever I put the function in a "function ajaxFunction(){" it doesn't work.